# Best way to create a submodel of a model in ASP.NET Core 6.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, model

In my ASP.NET Core MVC project, I have a class `Deck` that contains a `List<Card>? cards`. I have the basic Entity Framework CRUD functionality for creating decks, but I can't figure out how to add a card to a specific list. Ideally, from the deck details page, I would be able to create a card and add it directly to that users deck.

Currently, I tried scaffolding the `Card` controller and views, and passing in the deck id to the function, allowing me to get it from the `Create` function of the card controller, but this hasn't been working

```
string path = HttpContext.Request.Path;
card.DeckId = Int32.Parse(path.Replace("/Cards/Create/", ""));
card.Repetitions = 0;
card.ReviewInterval = 1;
card.EasinessFactor = 2.5f;
card.NextReview = DateTime.Now;

if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
     _context.Deck.Find(_context.Deck.Where(A => A.Id == card.DeckId)).Cards.Add(card);
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}

return View(card);
```

Perhaps I need to format the models differently, but right now I'm stuck on how to approach this

Comment: To add a Card to a Deck, you only need to set the `DeckId` foreign key property.   There's no need to fetch the Deck entity.  Also what does "but this hasn't been working" mean?

Comment: Wouldn't I need to fetch the deck to add the Card to it in the database? I haven't been able to get the DeckId from the URL and I don't know what other way to get the deckid to this card

Comment: Nope.  Only the entity with the foreign key property needs to be modified in the database.